# Base64Utils.encode does not produce valid base64 encoding

Tags: android, kotlin, base64, moshi

I am trying to encode a byte array in base64 before sending it over the network. The output of the `encode()` function below is not a valid base64 because what I read from my research was that the length of the string needs to a multiple of 4. Also, the string is not padded with "=" if the length is not a multiple of 4. I am assuming since no one has had this problem before, is there something wrong in the code below which is making the base64 to not be a multiple of 4?

```
    private val messageAdapter = Moshi.Builder()
        .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .build()
        .adapter(RealTimePayload::class.java)

    fun encode(realTimePayload: RealTimePayload): String? {
        val jsonPayload = messageAdapter.toJson(realTimePayload)
        val compressedData = zip(jsonPayload)
        return Base64Utils.encode(compressedData)
    }

    fun decode(encodedString: String): RealTimePayload? {
        val gzippedData = Base64Utils.decode(encodedString)
        val jsonData = unzip(gzippedData)
        return messageAdapter.fromJson(jsonData)
    }

    private fun unzip(content: ByteArray): String =
        GZIPInputStream(content.inputStream()).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }

    private fun zip(content: String): ByteArray {
        val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        GZIPOutputStream(bos).bufferedWriter().use { it.write(content) }
        return bos.toByteArray()
    }
}
```

**Edit**: I should mention that the final encoded string has some trailing '='s but the length is still not a multiple of 4.
Let me know if I should provide more information? Thanks.

Comment: Where are you getting `Base64Utils` from? The Android SDK has a `Base64` class, but not `Base64Utils` AFAIK. I do not see that class as part of standard Kotlin, either.

Comment: from `com.google.android.gms.common.util.Base64Utils`. It in turn is making a call to `Base64`

Comment: Why are you Base64 encoding a string before it goes over the network? That's not as a security measure is it?

Answer (score 0):

Are there some line terminators in the encoded string?

The `com.google.android.gms.common.util.Base64Utils#encode` passes flag `0` to the `Base64#encodeToString`. This means the result will be a multi-lined, padded, non url-safed string.